# why is this if statement redirecting users to next webpage

Tags: php, if-statement, header

I want to have the user continue onto the next page after clicking the submit button but instead right when this page loads it redirects the users to the next page.  Also this code is giving me errors on the "else" statement above the header.

```
<center>

<?php
        include "functions.inc";
        $datafile = "users.dat";
        if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST))
// Function to check the password length
            {
            $the_user = $_POST['newuser'];
            var_dump($the_user);

            $users = arrayfile_to_array($datafile);
            // Validate user name and password

            // If valid, save to the file of users
            $users[] = $the_user;
            array_to_arrayfile($users, $datafile);
            }
            else
            {
            if (!file_exists($datafile))  // Data file doesn't exist, so create it
            {
                $users = array();
        array_to_arrayfile($users, $datafile);
            }
            else 
            {
                $users = arrayfile_to_array($datafile);
            }
            else
            {
            if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST))     
            {
            header('Location: 04invoice.php');
            }
            }








?>
  <form name="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="post"> 
      Username: <input type="text" name="newuser[username]">
      <br>Password: <input type="text" name="newuser[password]">
      <br>Confirm Password: <input type="text" name="newuser[confirm_password]">    
          <br>Email: <input type="text" name="newuser[mail]">


      </select><br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign Up"> 
  </form>

</center>
```

Comment: Please format your code.. it looks like you have 2 elses back to back

Comment: You cannot use `header()` after you've output something to the page.  That `<center>` tag will prevent any `header()` call from being successful.

Comment: You have an `if` `else` `else`.  Did you mean to use an `elseif`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two else's in a way that is semantically meaningless and syntactically invalid:

```
        if (!file_exists($datafile))  // Data file doesn't exist, so create it
        {
            $users = array();
    array_to_arrayfile($users, $datafile);
        }
        else 
        {
            $users = arrayfile_to_array($datafile);
        } //HERE -------------------------------------------
        else
        {
        if (array_key_exists('submit', $_POST))     
        {
        header('Location: 04invoice.php');
        }
        }
```

What is "else else" supposed to do?

I would also suggest properly indenting your code; it will make seeing which parts of your logic correspond to each other far easier.